# JWT Authentication Failed with SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, jwt

I have a REST API (core 2.1) which need to support a SPA, providing restful endpoints and some live-interactive features using SignalR;

The Hub/MVC routes are running on the same server, which is also the  provider of the JWT token.

After loggin in, the client-side receives a JWT token, which places on the header for every REST request, otherwise it gets a 401 (This is working with the `[Authorize]` attribute).

At the client-side, the code below tries to connect to my /hub endpoint: 
`new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(HUB_URL, { accessTokenFactory: () => this.getToken() })`
And if I place `[Authorize]` at my Hub class, I get the following error (Without the authorization, the client can send and listen correctly):

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:5001/hub?id=MY_ID&access_token=MY_TOKEN' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available

The server logged failed authentications:

> (Triggered a console.log on AddJwtBearerOptions.Events.OnMessageReceived)
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/hub? 
>    id=MY_ID&access_token=MY_TOKEN
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
>         Authorization failed.
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
>         AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 0.3658ms 401

Differently from the those requests, using the SAME JWT TOKEN with the REST ones (Using `[Authorize]`), with the `Header: Bearer XXXX` instead of  querystring, triggers the `OnTokenValidated`. The `OnAuthenticationFailed` is never triggered, even if the authentication fails:

> (Triggered a console.log on AddJwtBearerOptions.Events.OnMessageReceived)
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/api/products application/json
>   (Triggered a console.log on AddJwtBearerOptions.Events.OnTokenValidated)
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[2]
>         Successfully validated the token.

---

### Check below my ´Startup.cs`

`ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection)`

```
services.AddSignalR();
services.AddCors(option => option.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", p => p.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials()));
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options => {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters{
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:SecurityKey"]))
    };
});
```

`Configure(IApplicationBuilder)`

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseMvc();
app.UseSignalR(routes => {
     routes.MapHub<ApplicationHub>("/hub");
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You also need to add this block inside the `.AddJwtBearer` section:

```
// We have to hook the OnMessageReceived event in order to
// allow the JWT authentication handler to read the access
// token from the query string when a WebSocket or 
// Server-Sent Events request comes in.
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
{
    OnMessageReceived = context =>
    {
        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

        // If the request is for our hub...
        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
            (path.StartsWithSegments("/hub")))
        {
            // Read the token out of the query string
            context.Token = accessToken;
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

This can be found here in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: You just absolutely made my day @marcusturewicz. Thank you!!

Answer (score 7):

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
>   Authorization failed.
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
>   AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>   Request finished in 0.3658ms 401

Spend 20 hours for fixing. :(
Reason was in:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class ChatHub : Hub<IChatClient>
```

My service configuration:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options => ...)
```

UPD:
Full work example with JS client [here](https://github.com/Cular/SignalRJwtAuthTest).

Comment: You made my day! thanx

Comment: You can also use it like: [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]. The same result

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what `@marcusturewicz` already have stated, one should also check for the token inside the `Authorization` header in case if the access token is sent in the header instead of query.

Although, this may vary from how e.g., the client implementer sends the token.

```cs
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
{
    OnMessageReceived = context =>
    {
        // If no token is present in the query, we can
        // try to get it from the Authorization header.
        StringValues accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"] == StringValues.Empty
                ? context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]
                : context.Request.Query["access_token"];

        // If the request is for our hub...
        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
            (path.StartsWithSegments("/hub")))
        {
            // Read the token out of the query string
            context.Token = accessToken;
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```